# How to return or get response value from Volley onResponse method?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm getting string values from a web and storing them in a arraylist in onResponse method but when I access that list outside of the onResponse method it shows empty. I know in asyntask we simply get it in main thread like result = ayncClassName.execute(url).get(); So how to get in volley Any suggestions as I'm beginner in android.

Here's the code!

```
stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            String[] result = response.split("<div id=\"sidebar\">");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(result[0]);
            while (m.find())
            {
                urls.add(m.group(1));
            }
            p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
            m = p.matcher(result[0]);
            while (m.find())
            {
                names.add(m.group(1));
            }

            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textView.setText("Error");
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Random random = new Random();
    cs = random.nextInt(urls.size()); //got error here because arraylist is empty! 
    imageRequest = new ImageRequest(urls.get(cs), new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textView.setText("Error");
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

Comment: please show us your onResponse method code.

Comment: i posted it, Check it